# Remove words from column if present in list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with column 'text' which has many rows consisting of english sentences.

text

```
It is evening
Good morning
Hello everyone
What is your name
I'll see you tomorrow
```

I have a variable of type List which has some words such as

```
val removeList = List("Hello", "evening", "because", "is")
```

I want to remove all those words from column text which are present in removeList.

So my output should be

```
It
Good morning
everyone
What your name
I'll see you tomorrow
```

How can I do this using Spark Scala.

I wrote a code something like this:

```
val stopWordsList = List("Hello", "evening", "because", "is");
val df3 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT text FROM table");
val df4 = df3.map(x => cleanText(x.mkString, stopWordsList));

def cleanText(x:String, stopWordsList:List[String]):Any = {
  for(str <- stopWordsList) {
    if(x.contains(str)) {
      x.replaceAll(str, "")
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting error

```
Error:(44, 12) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
val df4 = df3.map(x => cleanText(x.mkString, stopWordsList));

Error:(44, 12) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[String])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String].
```

Unspecified value parameter evidence$6.
    val df4 = df3.map(x => cleanText(x.mkString, stopWordsList));

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You may take a look to this [link - how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this a future questions. Specially, you should provide some research effort and/or some code to probe you already tried to solve your problem by yourself.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. I updated it with what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this df and rdd way.

```
val df = Seq(("It is evening"),("Good morning"),("Hello everyone"),("What is your name"),("I'll see you tomorrow")).toDF("data")
val removeList = List("Hello", "evening", "because", "is")
val rdd2 = df.rdd.map{ x=> {val p = x.getAs[String]("data") ; val k = removeList.foldLeft(p) ( (p,t) => p.replaceAll("\\b"+t+"\\b","") ) ; Row(x(0),k) } }
spark.createDataFrame(rdd2, df.schema.add(StructField("new1",StringType))).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|data                 |new1                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
|It is evening        |It                   |
|Good morning         |Good morning         |
|Hello everyone       | everyone            |
|What is your name    |What  your name      |
|I'll see you tomorrow|I'll see you tomorrow|
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: add import org.apache.spark.sql._ for the Row object

Comment: Great, this works! I did just one small change (p,t) => p.replaceAll("\\b" + t + "\\b" , ""). The replaceAllLiterally will replace all occurrences, instead it should replace only if it is a complete word. For example, if my List has 'a', then all occurrences of 'a' would be replaced instead it should replace only if it is a word by itself.

Comment: I also did one more change, might help someone: (p,t) => p.replaceAll("\\b" + t + "\\b" , "").replaceAll(" +", " "). Additional replace all is to remove/convert multiple spaces to a single space. This can happen if more than one word is replaced. You can also add additional .replaceAll("""[\p{Punct}&&[^.]]""", "") to remove punctuations

Comment: I have one more column named rating in my dataframe of type Int. We are currently doing x=> {val p = x.getAs[String]("data") ; with the assumption we have just one column named data. What other changes do I need to accommodate this change?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me.
**Spark** *version* `2.3.0`, **Scala** *version* `2.11.8`.

## Using Datasets

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val data = List(
  "It is evening",
  "Good morning",
  "Hello everyone",
  "What is your name",
  "I'll see you tomorrow"
)
val removeList = List("Hello", "evening", "because", "is")

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
import spark.implicits._

def cleanText(text: String, removeList: List[String]): String =
  removeList.fold(text) {
    case (text, termToRemove) => text.replaceAllLiterally(termToRemove, "")
  }

val df1 = sc.parallelize(data).toDS // Dataset[String]
val df2 = df1.map(text => cleanText(text, removeList)) // Dataset[String]
```

## Using DataFrames

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val data = List(
  "It is evening",
  "Good morning",
  "Hello everyone",
  "What is your name",
  "I'll see you tomorrow"
)
val removeList = List("Hello", "evening", "because", "is")

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
import spark.implicits._

def cleanText(text: String, removeList: List[String]): String =
  removeList.fold(text) {
    case (text, termToRemove) => text.replaceAllLiterally(termToRemove, "")
  }

// Creates a temp table.
sc.parallelize(data).toDF("text").createTempView("table")

val df1 = spark.sql("SELECT text FROM table") // DataFrame = [text: string]
val df2 = df1.map(row => cleanText(row.getAs[String](fieldName = "text"), removeList)).toDF("text") // DataFrame = [text: string]
```

Comment: Given `sqlContext.sql` returns a **Dataframe** instead of a **Dataset**, you have three options. One is to use `mkString` as you did in your code to transform the **Row** to a **String**. Second use `getAs[String]("text")` or `getString(0)` on the row, to select the first _("text")_ **Column** value. Third, transform the **Dataframe** to a **Dataset[String]** using the `as[String]` method.

Comment: I have imported spark.implicits. I tried Option 1, 2 and 3. I am getting the same error for all the three **'Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset'**

Comment: I did spark-submit --version in my cmd (Windows) and it shows Spark version 2.3.0 and Scala 2.11. I have these properties in my pom.xml
 <properties>
        <spark.hdp.version>2.3</spark.hdp.version>
        <scala.version>2.11.0</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    </properties>

Comment: @Nick, I have updated the answer to provide an example using **DataFrames** and the `sql` method, it works fine for me. Try just running my little example in a **_spark-shell_**, maybe the error is caused by other part of the code - remember that if you run it in a spark-shell, you don't need to create the **SparkSession** _(`spark`)_ nor the **SparkContext** _(`sc`)_, but you still need to `import spark.implicits._`.

Comment: Thanks @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, I have the exact same code in my IntelliJ IDEA but it fails to run, giving me the same error as mentioned above, not sure why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183864/discussion-between-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez-and-nick).